# Creating a list to hold objects in C++

Tags: c++

Forgive me if this seems a bit naive, but I'm rather new to C++ and after years in C and in Java, I guess my head's a little confused.

I'm trying to make an array of an unknown size full of nodes that I've created.

```
node *aNode = new node(14,32);
std::list<node> dataSet;
std::list<node>::iterator it;
it = dataSet.begin();
dataSet.insert(it, aNode)
```

However, when I compile this (proof of concept test), it refuses, throwing all sorts of errors.

I know it's something simple and I just can't figure it out.
Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

edit:
Here's node:

```
class node{
    float startPoint;
    float endPoint;
    float value;
public:
    node(float, float);
    void setValues(float, float);
};

node::node(float start, float end){
    startPoint = start;
    endPoint = end;
}
```

and compiler errors:

> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> error C2371: 'it' : redefinition; different basic types
>
> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from
>   'std::list<_Ty>::_Iterator<_Secure_validation>' to 'int'
>
> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'dataSet'
>
> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
>
> error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> error C2371: 'dataSet' : redefinition; different basic types

update:
I changed the little bit of code to:

```
 node aNode(14, 32);
 std::list<node> dataSet;
 dataSet.insert(dataSet.begin(), aNode);
```

But these 3 errors remain:

```
 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
 error C2371: 'dataSet' : redefinition; different basic types
```

Comment: can you post the compiler error?

Comment: could you please show us the node class?

Comment: aren't you trying to insert a `node*` into a `node` list?

Comment: Tiago is right.  Declare it as a local variable : node aNode(14, 32); then it should be happy to put it into the list

Comment: @GrahamGriffiths That didn't help :/ I added the errors and the node class to the main post.

Comment: Where are you declaring the class `node`? It seems that the compiler can't find it when it tries to compile the rest of the code.

Comment: Apparently you already declared the `dataSet` variable. Is there more code in the function where you use this snippet? Maybe the rest of the function causes the remaining errors...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your list should either be of type `std::list<node*>` or you should insert a node object (and not a pointer to one).

```
node *aNode = new node(14, 32);
std::list<node*> dataSet;
dataSet.insert(dataSet.begin(), aNode);
```

or

```
node aNode(14, 32);
std::list<node> dataSet;
dataSet.insert(dataSet.begin(), aNode);
```

Comment: This got rid of a bunch of the errors, but 3 still remain:
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2371: 'dataSet' : redefinition; different basic types

Comment: @user1848437 You might post that as an "update" section of your question for everyone to see easily.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to declare your list to contain node pointers, i.e.:

```
std::list<node*> dataSet
std::list<node*>::iterator it;
```

Also worth noting that you can add items to a list without using an iterator:

```
dataSet.push_back(aNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

aNode is pointer to a node object on the heap.

dataSet should be defined as:

```
std::list<node*> dataSet;
```

Same with your iterator:

```
std::list<node*>::iterator it;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the code you posted your missing a semicolon after the last parenthesis

try

```
dataSet.insert(it, aNode);
```

Comment: Since this may just be a copy/paste error, rather than what's actually being compiled by the OP, it's probably best to ask if the missing `;` is in the source code or was a copy/paste error via a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @user1848437 Might want to edit in a `;` to your question then ;)

Answer (score 0):

"missing type specifier - int assumed"
can be due to missing

`#include <list>`

or a missing

`#include "header for node"`